# Moq How to use SetupAllProperties on a get only interface

Tags: c#, moq

I wanted to see if there is a way to get this

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int MyProp { get; }
}

[Fact]
public void Test
{
    var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    mock.SetupAllProperties();
    mock.Object.MyProp = 12; // this does not work because there is a get.
}
```

I know i can use 
`mock.SetupGet` but since there are lots of properties on my interface, I do not want to do `SetupGet` on each one of them.

Comment: Do you want all the properties to return `12`? Are all properties of type `int`?

Comment: How are you using your mock such that you need all the properties to be setup? Perhaps you need a fake (dummy data) instead of a mock for which you could use something like [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)

Comment: It seems what you want is just a normal mock with MockBehaviour.Loose (which is the default), so I don't really understand what is your problem

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen no each property will have its own value. The problem here is strongly typed values without going through the cumbersome process of having to code up SetupGet to be able to specify a value.  If the above interface had a setter as well, it would have just worked.

Answer (score 0):

You did not respond to my comment, but if you want to use reflection, you can find all properties (of the relevant type) and create `Setup` for each with this (the directive `using System.Linq.Expressions;` is needed for `Expression` class to be in scope; we create our own expression trees):

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();

var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IFoo));
foreach (var property in typeof(IFoo)
  .GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int))
  )
{
  var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<IFoo, int>>(
    Expression.Property(parameterExpression, property),
    parameterExpression);
  mock.Setup(lambdaExpression).Returns(12);
}
```

---

Later addition: Not sure I really understand your question.

If you have many properties with many values, strongly typed, you can either do:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mock.Setup(x => x.MyProp).Returns(12);
mock.Setup(x => x.MyOtherProp).Returns(3.14);
mock.Setup(x => x.MyThirdProp).Returns("test");
...
mock.Setup(x => x.MyLastProp).Returns(new DateTime(2015, 1, 1));
var objToUse = mock.Object;
```

or do:

```
var rep = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
var objToUse = rep.OneOf((IFoo x) =>
    x.MyProp == 12
    && x.MyOtherProp == 3.14
    && x.MyThirdProp == "test"
    && ...
    && x.MyLastProp == new DateTime(2015, 1, 1)
    );
```

I do not think it can be made less cumbersome. If you want a loose mock, there is `var objToUse = Mock.Of((IFoo x) => x.MyProp == 12 && ...);`, almost a one-liner.

Comment: Yes however that seems to be a workaround, look at my reply to your comment.

Comment: @HarshGupta Not sure I see your problem, but see my edited answer above.